# Firestore - only able to create two collections at a time

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am uploading an initial data to firebase-firestore. The data is to be used as a fixture to develop my frontend further. I do not have errors, at least haven't caught one yet. The following two functions, are being used to upload data: 
**Edited to explain better**

```
async function uploadData() {
  const userId = 'AKFROjo1isTPRfjYYDsSehwZdIi1';

  const itemsListRef = await db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('userData').doc('itemsList');
  await itemsListRef.set({ created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() });

   await summaryList.forEach(async summary => {
    await itemsListRef.collection('summaryList').add(summary);
   });

   await coreCompetencyList.forEach(async coreCompetency => {
     await itemsListRef.collection('coreCompetencyList').add(coreCompetency);
   });

}
```

and a second function as -

```
async function uploadData2() {
  const userId = 'AKFROjo1isTPRfjYYDsSehwZdIi1';

  const itemsListRef = await db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('userData').doc('itemsList');
  await itemsListRef.set({ created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() });

  await educationList.forEach(async education => {
    await itemsListRef.collection('educationList').add(education);
  });

  await categoryList.forEach(async category => {
    await itemsListRef.collection('categoryList').add(category);
  });
}
```

It is being called as :

```
async function main() {
  try {
    await uploadData();
    await app.delete();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Data upload failed, reason:', e, '\n\n');
  }
}
main().then(r => console.log('Done.'));
```

**I am surprised that I cannot put all 4 calls in a single function**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug.  This is the way it was intended to work.

In actuality, collections are not really entities that require creation or deletion like folders in a filesystem.  They are just virtual containers for documents that spring into existence immediately when the first document in created under it, and automatically disappear when the last document in deleted.  You can think of them more like units of organization that make indexing and security rules possible to implement.

Comment: Yes, but why am I able to not create  -- as many collections (4 in my case) each containing a single document. Why is it creating two collections with one function call. Can you point me where I should look in the documentation. I am able to create all 4 collections at one time if i put two calls in separate function and call it in main (). It is not intuitive to me as yet.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.  Be sure to explain what happens that's different than your expectations, and if there is an error, catch it and show the message.  One thing to note is that await inside a foreach loop probably doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Correctly pointed out about the forEach loop. updating the post shortly